# Getting xml error while exporting excel file

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I have below code to export excel file. File is exporting with correct data. But when file is opened it gives error(Removed Records: Column information from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part ).
I have googled but couldn't resolve the problem.

Below is my code

```
ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage();
ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Report" + " - " + ((PictureBox)(sender)).Tag.ToString());
HeaderOfExcel(excelWorksheet, ((PictureBox)(sender)).Tag.ToString());

                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i < stk.Count; i++)
                    {

                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 1].Value = stk[i].Rf.ToString();
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 2].Value = stk[i].Desc.ToString();
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 3].Value = stk[i].Stock;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 4].Value = stk[i].MinStock;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 5].Value = stk[i].Maxtock;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 6].Value = stk[i].Price;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 6].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00000";
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 7].Value = stk[i].Value;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 7].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00000";
                        totalValue += stk[i].Value;                        
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 8].Value = stk[i].Location.ToString() ;

                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 7].Style.Numberformat.Format = "0.00000";
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 7].Value = totalValue.ToString("n5") + " " + curr;
                        excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 1].Value = "Total";


                        using (ExcelRange range = excelWorksheet.Cells["A" + (i + 3) + ":H" + (i + 3)])
                        {


                            range.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                            range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightGray);
                            range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Left;
                            range.Style.Font.Bold = true;

                        }
                        using (ExcelRange range = excelWorksheet.Cells[i + 3, 8])
                        {
                            range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                            range.Style.Font.Bold = true;


                        }

                    }


                    clsMethods.WriteToFile(package);
```

.

```
static internal void WriteToFile(ExcelPackage package)
    {
            string path = "";               
            SaveFileDialog SaveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
            SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            SaveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            path = SaveFileDialog1.FileName ;
            FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(path);
            if (newFile.Exists)
            {
                newFile.Delete();
                newFile = new FileInfo(path);
            }
            FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
            package.SaveAs(file);
            file.Close();
    }
```

Your help may appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Hi hi, it would be useful if you could get rid of all the code that doesn't add to the problem at hand. For example, does the error still occur if you get rid of the entire `for` loop (etc.)

Comment: I couldn't trace out where the actual problem is. Thanks for reply. :)

Comment: Please help me out

Comment: Sorry, can't debug this at the moment. I'd just recommend taking out as much code as possible and narrowing down where the problem occurs.

Comment: I am not getting any problem in code. File is exporting fine with data.
After opening this file it is giving error. I tried that file open from another systems.